# GCP Instance startup script error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, shell-scripting

Trying to add a startup script following the sample here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

The instance is created with no problems but the script does not execute.  Console shows the following output:

```
Jul 28 15:54:39 testclient-pbx startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.

Jul 28 15:54:39 testclient-pbx startup-script: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.

Jul 28 15:54:39 hostname startup-script: INFO startup-script: /bin/bash: /startup-aVpN6i/tmpVVdFyB: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Jul 28 15:54:39 hostname startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 126.

Jul 28 15:54:39 hostname startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
```

I'm actually trying to run more complex script but was receiving same error.  Using `debian-cloud/debian-9` image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using VScode on Win platform and as you can see above the message hinted file was not found. I had to change CRLF in VScode to LF "Unix" style and script now runs correctly!  In VScode just click the CRLF bottom right and change to LF.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are passing a hidden symbol ^M

I would recommend you to inspect the file with vim and set the following command to show you the hidden characters:

```
:set list
```

Comment: Thank you @miguelfrancisco85.  Yes, this would have helped me find the issue.  As stated above this was due to file being created in windows platform and using CRLF instead of *nix LF.